# Is it true that if $A$ is a measurable subset of a measurable set $B$ with $0<m(A) = m(B) < \infty,$ then $A = B.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure.

Is the following true?

> **Claim**: If $A$ is a measurable subset of a measurable set $B$ with $0<m(A) = m(B) < \infty,$ then $A = B.$

Actually I am trying to solve the following problem:

> **Question**: For each positive integer $n,$ let $E_n$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$ with $m(E_n) = 1.$
>       Prove that 
>   $$\displaystyle m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \right) = 1.$$

If the claim above does not hold, then how should I solve the question?

Comment: For your "Claim" consider $A=(0,1)$ and $B=[0,1]$ ......

Comment: @Fred: Oops. I think I was not thinking when I wrote the claim just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is not true.

Counterexample: compare the sets $A=[0,1)$ and $B=[0,1]$.

There $A$ is a **proper** subset of $B$ with $m(A)=m(B)=1<\infty$.

---

In the sequel we work in space $[0,1]$ so for every $A\subseteq[0,1]$ notation $A^{\complement}$ stands for $[0,1]-A$.

---

Note that $m(E_n^{\complement})+1=m(E_n^{\complement})+m(E_n)=m([0,1])=1$ for every $n$, so that $m(E_n^{\complement})=0$ for every $n$.

Consequently:

$$m\left(\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\right)^{\complement}\right)=m\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n^{\complement}\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}m\left(E_n^{\complement}\right)=0\text{  implying that }m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\right)=1$$